# Row editing is not being disabled in the grid Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Even if the isAdmin value is false, the row editing is still being enabled. I think the bind property in view is not working. If any would be able to help on it. Thank you.
Code in View:

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
clicksToEdit: 2,
pluginId: 'rowEditor',
listeners: {
    cancelEdit: 'onCancelClick',
    edit: 'onEditClick'
},
bind: {
    disabled: '{!isAdmin}'
}});
```

Another part of code in controller:

```
 init: function () {
    var access = (user_Access[0].Admin == 'True');
    if (access) {
        var vm = this.getViewModel();
        vm.set("isAdmin", access);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your view model you should use view model data and [formulas](https://docs.sencha.com/ext/6.5.1/modern/Ext.app.bind.Formula.html) to achieve this and as per Sencha best practices:

```js
viewModel: {
    data: {
        isAdmin: false
    },
    formulas: {
        disabled: function(get) {
            return get('isAdmin') ? false : true
        }
    }
}
...
bind: {
    disabled: '{disabled}'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Akrion but how my code is working for the tbar buttons as in the below code:
  tbar: [{
        text: 'Add',
        reference: 'Add',
        handler: 'onAddClick',
        iconCls: "icon-add",
        bind: {
            visible: '{isAdmin}'
        }
    }

Comment: thank you so much for your help and time. I have following code in a sencha fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kr6

Comment: the concept of my coding only in the above sencha fiddle

Comment: I am using Sencha 6.0. The above code is a sample of the code I am using

Comment: Sencha 6.0 Neptune

Comment: If anyone can help on this, it will be greatly appreciated. I have been spending a lot of time on it and tried different ways as well.  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kr6

Comment: please help on this.@Akrion

Comment: Look at this example. I have the editing of the grid controlled via the formula: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2krd

Comment: It is working but displaying the update and cancel button and user is able to click it. @Akrion

Comment: Thank you @Akrion. I made it to work using beforeedit event.

Comment: Awesome. Hopefully my answer helped. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, @Akrion. Thanks a lot.